# Could not understand confluent cloud metrics api ISO 8601 time interval

Tags: datetime, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

From the doc:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cloud/metrics-api.html

```
"intervals": [
        "2019-12-19T11:00:00-05:00/2019-12-19T11:05:00-05:00"
    ]
```

What is this interval format? I never knew a time format extending `-05:00` in date time `2019-12-19T11:00:00` ? What is this?  can someone clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Timezone. UTC-5 (`-05:00`) is U.S. Eastern Time

Comment: thanks, i never knew of it and neither found anything in google useful near to what you answered. again thanks.

Comment: Oh, really?  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC